# Object does not match target type PropertyInfo.GetValue()

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

Im fairly new to .net and would love to get some help with reflection. I have searched everywhere and i cant seem to get this right.

I've got a function which takes in a generic list of my custom class and i am iterating over extracting the properties of the classes and creating a spreadsheet. My issue is when i try to get the value of the property, i get an exception saying 'Object does not match the target value'.

I know this might be a duplicate but i was unable to find anything and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private static Task<SheetData> GenerateSheetDataPart<T>(List<T> data){
//some speadsheet logic

foreach (var dataModel in data){
    //some more spreadsheet logic
    Type type = dataModel.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props){
        cell.DataType = await ResolveCellDataTypeOnValue((string)prop.GetValue(prop)); //exception here. function returns Number or String based what value is.
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue((string)prop.GetValue(prop);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Should be `prop.GetValue(dataModel)` I presume you are sure they are all `string`

Comment: Correct. All properties on the class are string